# iviewer jquery pluggin, center image

Tags: jquery-plugins, zooming

I'm using the iviewer plugin with a lightbox and I have issue to center my image everytime it load a new image.
I know that there is a pre-built method center() I just don't undertand how and where to call it.

You can find the function I'm using under. The function is called when I click on an element, it open a box div(#iviewer). In which I would like my image center. I also use a zoom pourcentage at the beginning so my image doesn't fit the box (var viewer).

```
function open(src, id) {

    var firstZoom = true;
    $("#iviewer").fadeIn().trigger('fadein');
    var viewer = $("#iviewer .viewer").     
    width(920).
    height(560).
    iviewer({
        src : src,
        ui_disabled : true,
        zoom : '50%',
        initCallback : function() {
           var self = this;
         },
        onZoom : function() {
           if (!firstZoom) return;

           $("#iviewer .loader").fadeOut();
           $("#iviewer .viewer").fadeIn();
           firstZoom = true;
       }
    }

 );
 //load new pic
 viewer.iviewer('loadImage', src);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The "onFinishLoad" callback hook in the initialization worked for me:

```
onFinishLoad: function(ev, src){ viewer.iviewer('center')}
```